# Remove rows in data.frame when the entire row values match a regex, or match a group of values

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this (correct values ​​are just an example):

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(" ","NO_DATA","   "," ",NA,NA,3),
                 b=c("NO_DATA","NO_DATA",""," ",NA,2," "),
                 c=c("NO_DATA","NO_DATA","","",NA,2,3),
                 d=c("NO_DATA","NO_DATA","","",NA,2,3),
                 e=c("  ","NO_DATA","","",NA,2,"NO_DATA"))

        a       b       c       d       e
1         NO_DATA NO_DATA NO_DATA          <- I want to Remove this
2 NO_DATA NO_DATA NO_DATA NO_DATA NO_DATA  <- I want to Remove this
3                                          <- I want to Remove this
4                                          <- I want to Remove this
5    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  <- I want to Remove this
6    <NA>       2       2       2       2  <- Preserve
7       3               3       3 NO_DATA  <- Preserve
```

**I need to remove all rows with values: "", " " (or any number of just spaces),`NA`,"NO_DATA"; but present in all columns in the same row**.

I tried using subset, but the logic seems to be wrong since even this:

```
subset(df, a != "NO_DATA" & b != "NO_DATA")
```

results in a wrong result:

```
    a b c d       e
3                  
4                  
7   3   3 3 NO_DATA
```

This is the result I want:

```
     a       b       c       d       e   
6    <NA>       2       2       2       2  
7       3               3       3 NO_DATA
```

I would like to use a regex beacuse possible values could vary

Comment: Instead of removing rows that contain x, y, or z, do you want to keep rows that contain a numeric value, e.g. `df[rowSums(suppressWarnings(sapply(df, as.numeric)), na.rm = TRUE) > 0, ]`?

Comment: No, this numeric values are just an example, could be any string or number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subset using:

```
df[rowSums(!sapply(df, function(x) trimws(x) %in% c("", "NO_DATA") | is.na(x))) > 0, ]

     a b c d       e
6 <NA> 2 2 2       2
7    3   3 3 NO_DATA
```

Comment: `c("", "NO_DATA")` would  work as a blacklist, great.

Comment: @Emeeus, that blacklist does not work with your example data as you have `""` and `" "` and `"   "`  if they are all the same then we could for example do `df[df == "NO_DATA" | df == ""] <- NA;     df[apply(df,1,function(x) !all(is.na(x))),]`. But I'm not sure that this is really any better than @27ϕ9's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is way to remove using regex (i.e., `grepl()`) and `is.na()` to identify `NA` values.

First uses `rapply()` to create a `TRUE`/`FALSE` dataframe to filter with. Then there are a couple ways to filter from there. Note, that if you have a very large dataframe using `rowMeans()` will coerce it into a matrix (so that may be slow). Usually not an issue, but an important caveat. Hope this helps!!

```
# Replace each cell with T/F based on the function (grepl() / is.na())
idx_df <- rapply(df, function(x) grepl("^(\\s*|NO_DATA)$", x) | is.na(x), how = "replace")

# Check if there were no matches in the function (i.e., there is at least one FALSE)
idx <- do.call(pmin, idx_df) == 0

# Check is the rowMean is less than 1 (not all TRUE)
idx2 <- rowMeans(idx_df) < 1

identical(idx, idx2) # same result
[1] TRUE

df[idx, ]
     a b c d       e
6 <NA> 2 2 2       2
7    3   3 3 NO_DATA
```

Also, if it makes more sense to you conceptually, you can negate (`!`) `grepl()` and `is.na()` inside `rapply()` and go from there. Whatever is easier to read!